# Two bindings; One Works, Other Doesn't. Why?

Tags: wpf

Why does one label update but not the other? Both bound to the same property. I assume there's a problem with the binding being in a dataTemplate? Using Resharper I'm told that my `lblOverallInt` cannot resolve the symbol. How could I fix this?

```
<Label Name="lbl1" Content="{Binding Path=lblOverallInt, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

<Expander>
    <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Name="lbl2" Content="{Binding Path=lblOverallInt, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
</Expander>
```

**UPDATE**

Related follow on question; I have the following style binding also which works when applied to the label but not to the Expander. Is there a similar process for wiring this up as mm8 solution to the top part of this question?

**Added separate solution for this part**

```
<Expander.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=lblOverallInt}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=lblOverallInt, Converter={StaticResource isZeroConverter}}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Expander.Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataContext` of the `HeaderTemplate` is the header itself. Try this:

```
<Expander>
    <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Name="lbl2" Content="{Binding Path=DataContext.lblOverallInt,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Expander}}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
</Expander>
```

Or this:

```
<Expander Header="{Binding Path=lblOverallInt}">
    <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Name="lbl2" Content="{Binding}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
</Expander>
```

Comment: Awesome, that works. Could you have a look at the update above? I have a style binding also that I'm wondering how to also apply this solution too.

Answer (score 0):

For part 2 of my question I had the style binding part still attached to the Expander when it actually needed to be included in the DataTemplate;

```
<Expander.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border Height="24">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="0">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource isZeroConverter}}" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Style.Resources>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Style>
                <Label>Errors/Warnings:</Label>
                <Label Name="lbl2" Content="{Binding}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Expander.HeaderTemplate>
```